# Mean pairwise traits dissimilarity for non-integers data

Tags: r, euclidean-distance, vegan

I am beginner in R, currently i was trying to quantify mean pairwise trait dissimilarity between plot pairs using a community weighted mean (CWM) data comprises of 70 plots including 7 CWM traits. But while executing R codes for mean pairwise trait dissimilarity, i am facing error for non-integers. please guide me how to resolve this issue. Thank you
The details are mentioned below.

`comm` (the data)

```
Trait1    Trait2    Trait3  Trait4  Trait5  Trait6  Trait7
1   6.02  138.36     0.48   16.51    0.81   43.19   6.35
2  36.81  132.72     0.42    5.75    0.24   71.09   2.55
3   8.52  128.79     0.46   17.46    0.63   44.30   7.06
4  19.50  148.69     0.42   19.49    2.07   27.01   5.49
5  18.35  140.18     0.43   21.40    0.72   28.60   6.08
```

R code

```
 { funct = avgdist(comm, 70, distfun = vegdist, meanfun = mean,
+     transf = NULL, iterations = 100, dmethod = "bray") }
```

Error produced

```
Error in rrarefy(inputcast, sample = sample) : 
  function is meaningful only for integers (counts)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Comment: The function is intended for a community matrix that contains the counts of individual species in different plots. Your data matrix contains decimal numbers not counts.

Comment: @dcarlson, Thanks for your comments ... would you please suggest any other package to estimate mean pairwise dissimilarity for CWM traits data (non-integers), if possible ?

Comment: Any of the distance measures in `dist()` might work or `daisy()` in package `cluster`.